# Extracting string from logs with regex in pig script

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I have log data and I want to extract each information into a variable

The following is sample one line log.
{:id=>306, :name=>"bblite", :cpu=>{:quota=>4, :allocated=>4, :actual=>0}, :memory=>{:quota=>8192, :allocated=>8192, :actual=>8578}, :cluster_stats=>{"wc1104"=>{:cpu=>0, :mem=>8578}}}

I need variable that have all ids,a variable that have all names,a variable that have CPUs and a variable that have all cluster stats

The following is the portion of my pig script. I can store the ids but I have no idea how to extract the rest of them using regex.

.
.
.

```
matching_messages = FILTER raw_lines BY (LOWER(message) MATCHES '.*cc_altus-plaform.*');

ids = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'id=>\\d*',0);

names = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'name=>\\"\\",',0);

line_with_date = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE
DateFormatter(timestamp) AS formatted_time: chararray, message;

DUMP names;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following codes snippet is the regex I have written which works:

```
id = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'(?<=id=>)\\d*',0);

name = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'name=>\\"[\\w]*\\"',0);

cpu = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REPLACE( REGEX_EXTRACT(message, 'cpu=>\\{.*?\\}',0), ',','');

memory = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'memory=>\\{.*?\\}',0);

cluster = FOREACH matching_messages GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'cluster_stats=>\\{.*?\\}',0);
```